# Use Wordpress to create a custom CMS?

Tags: customization, cms

I am new to Wordpress, but i am good with php, javascripts, SQL and with other stuff.
One of my friends asked me to do a site using Wordpress for his travel agency.

There should be ability to him, to add tour packages and update them, and also web site visitors should have a chance to register as a member on site and upload their photos, write reviews and rate each tour packages. I made a content management system for this, simply with php and SQL, but I don't know how to attach that system to Wordpress. I don't know if there is a way to do so.

Please tell me, then I can inform to my friend that it is impossible.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. One of the necessities of the site is that you have at least done some research before asking a question. You should also show your effort what you have tried/researched/code you've written and also explain where you are lacking. Also, please read [ask] :-). Thank you for understanding. BTW, my opinion, Wordpress is the best CMS platforms available :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen you mean i can built any system on wordpress? what is the boundarie ?

Comment: Yes, the sky is the limit. Go out and get creative with Wordpress

Comment: this is my last question, what is the benefit of building our system on wordpress platform than building it as our own site written from core.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through the WordPress APIs without writing any MySQL.

Use custom post types for your different content types and WordPress already handles subscriber registration, plugins like BuddyPress extend that.

If you want more specific help please include some code.

Comment: is that mean i can built any system on wordpress. there are no boundaries? as an example can i built Q & A site like this on wordpress platform. what is the limit. i am asking because i am realy new to wordpress. if you can give little description, it would be grate!

Comment: Yes, as long as it is possible withing PHP and MySQL.